# Call non-class function from a class method C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I want to call the function `print` which is outside the class.
At the forward declaration `void print(Entity* e)`, I'm getting errors like this:

```
'Entity' undeclared identifier  
'e' undeclared identifier  
'print' illegal use of type 'void'   
term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments (at the function call)-> `print(this);`  
'print': redefinition; previous definition was 'data variable' (at the definition of print)
```

**My Program**

```
void print(Entity* e);

class Entity {
public:
    int x, y;

    Entity(int x, int y) {
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
        print(this);
    }
};

void print(Entity* e)
{
    cout << e->x << " " << e->y << endl;
}

int main()
{
    Entity e(1, 2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: At the point of your forward function declaration of `print()` `Entity` isn't known by the compiler, because neither a class definition of forward class declaration was made before.

Comment: Please look into [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) and the documentation of your C++ compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) and debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first line of code, the compiler doesn't know what a `Entity` is. So add the following line to the top of your code:

```
class Entity;
```